# Cross compile qt application for Rasperry Pi

Tags: qt, embedded, arm

I want to build an example from the QT5 folder for my raspberry pi. I have a working cross compiler and qt5.0.2 installed on my ubuntu. Is this enough to build an application for my device? Do I have to provide any specific qt embedded libs? 
For example do I have to take the QT libs from my embedded linux for the applicaiotn on the host to build?

edit:
as mentioned here (http://qt-project.org/wiki/RaspberryPi_Beginners_guide) it says:

"Then go to the “Rasperry Pi” kit tab->System Environment and add LD_LIBRARY_PATH which is set to /usr/local/qt5pi/lib"

This is a qt version build for the PI. So yes I guess I need some specific QT libs which are build for my PI device. The question is now do I have to rebuild these on my own or can I get these from my device directly?

Comment: Take a look here: http://qt-project.org/wiki/RaspberryPi_Beginners_guide

Comment: yes but this includes compiling QT for the raspi but I deployed it using the packet manager so there was no need to build it on my own.

Comment: The link Cameron gives has more information than you need, but is has steps to use QCreator, etc which seems to answer your question.  Wheezy is a debian release which is very similar to Ubuntu.